# How to change the background color of Status Bar in WP8 silverlight?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Is there any way to change the Background Color of status bar in Windows Phone 8 silverlight application?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

It is quite easy to do that, but I'm not sure if it is reflected in the emulator (better try it on a real device).

Open the XAML of the page where you want to change the status bar and then change these properties the way you want them to be:

```
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
shell:SystemTray.BackgroundColor="#2440b2"
shell:SystemTray.ForegroundColor="White"
```

The *.IsVisible property ensures the status bar is visible, the *.BackgroundColor is setting the correct background of the status bar and finally the *.ForegroundColor changes the color of text and icons.

Comment: If this was the answer to your question, please keep in mind that you cannot set the ForegroundColor of the SystemTray to white. You'll need to pick a light gray or similar color. Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.systemtray.foregroundcolor

Comment: i want to change the background color of status bar,not system tray please see the image attached

Comment: If you mean this volume and music control panel, it is not possible to do that with the API.

Answer (score 0):

Check this property>>    `PhoneBackgroundColor`

Follow this link to get more details>>

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769552%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: Is it possible to change the status bar's background??

Comment: I think the PhoneBackgroundColor is not really connected to this issue. Check my post below.